# Linux: "fstab" with additional mount options?

Tags: linux, mount, glusterfs, fstab, options

I'm using "GlusterFS" Client, to mount the GlusterFS Volume on my Web Server. Below is the MOUNT command when i manually mount from commandline:

```
# mount -t glusterfs -o aux-gfid-mount gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html
```

I don't know how to put that `-o aux-gfid-mount` option inside the `/etc/fstab`. So my `fstab` is still, lacking of that option:

```
gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html/ glusterfs defaults,_netdev,fetch-attempts=5 0 0
```

How do i put that `-o aux-gfid-mount` option inside the `fstab` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say as a standard "mount" option within `fstab`, comma separated :

```
gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html/ glusterfs defaults,aux-gfid-mount,_netdev,fetch-attempts=5 0 0
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know it is as simple as that. Thank you! =)